# the minimumLineSpacing property of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

to the property minimumLineSpacing of UICollectionViewFlowLayout the apple's document said:

> For a vertically scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum
>   spacing between successive rows. For a horizontally scrolling grid,
>   this value represents the minimum spacing between successive columns

i test it and the part of code like this:

```
self.layout1 = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
self.layout1.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
self.layout1.minimumLineSpacing = 100.0f;
```

the result is that the minimumLineSpacing is still added between the rows but not the columns,but i have found that if this delegate method: `-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`return a fixed value it is ok, the minimumLineSpacing will be added between the columns ,but not if it return a dynamic value,what is the issue?

Comment: Seems that I have the same issue here :-(

Comment: You can see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777942/serious-bug-for-uicollectionview-minimuminteritemspacing-and-minimumlinespacing?noredirect=1#comment42150155_26777942) for more details.

Comment: ok，thank you,i will see it.